# Connecting a value obtained from pd.df['x'].mode()[0] to a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I am printing the most common value using df['x'].mode()[0], I get an int, however I want that int to be a string instead. So I created a dictionary with the keys being the same as all possible values of df['x'].mode()[0], with the values being the string I want to bring up, however I am not sure how to execute this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("chicago.csv")
df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
df['month'] = df['Start Time'].dt.month


month_dict = {1:'January', 2:'February', 3: 'March', 4 : 'April', 5:'May', 6:'June'}

most_common_month = df['month'].mode()[0]

if most_common_month in month_dict.keys():
       print('Most common month:',most_common_month)
```

For example the above code (if the .csv file is available) prints 6.
I would like it to print June instead.

Comment: `print('Most common month:', month_dict[most_common_month])`

Comment: Or you can use `df['month'] = df['Start Time'].dt.month_name()` and forget about `month_dict`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic because 90% of the post is irrelevant, while the actual question is simply how to index a dictionary, covered in any introductory tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap it with calender, which is a python import:

```
import calendar                                                                                                                                                                      

calendar.month_name[6]  

# June
```

```
print('Most common month:',calendar.month_name(most_common_month))
```